# Rails3 - Multiple queries or single query in controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hopefully a simple question around a rails best-practice.

Let's keep this super simple; say I have a task model that has an ID, description and status.

**In my controller I have an index action to return all tasks**

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.all
end
```

My question is, in my view, suppose I want to display the tasks in **separate** HTML tables according to their status.

**What is the best practice?**

a) Query the database multiple times in the index action, ie

```
def index
  @draft_tasks = Task.where(status: "Draft")
  @approved_tasks = Task.where(status: "Approved")
  @closed_tasks = Task.where(status: "Closed")
end
```

b) Query the database once, and filter in the contoller action

```
def index
  tasks = Task.all
  @draft_tasks = tasks.#somethinghere
  @approved_tasks = tasks.#somethinghere
  @closed_tasks = tasks.#somethinghere
end
```

c) Filter in the view

```
<% @tasks.each do |k, v| %>
  <% some if statement searching for the status I want %>
    # Some code to output the table
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

or

d) Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generally accepted best practices here are to keep controller methods thin and to keep logic out of the view. So with that in mind, one possible way to do this would be:

```
# model
class Task
  scope :drafts, where(:status => "Draft")
  scope :approved, where(:status => "Approved")
  scope :closed, where(:status => "Closed")
end

# controller
def index
  @draft_tasks = Task.drafts
  @approved_tasks = Task.approved
  @closed_tasks = Task.closed
end
```

This will make 3 queries to the database, which could become a performance concern down the road, but if that does happen, you can optimize it at the model level (e.g. by defining class methods `drafts`, `approved`, and `closed` where the first one called prefetches everything). It's less elegant though, so don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: Thank you Ben, i appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: This answer is completely orthogonal to your question. This is your case A, with the `where` just moved to a scope. I don't get how it answers the question.

Comment: I don't want to get into a pissing match. The question asked for best practices, and I listed a few, along with an example that yes, is basically case A with a slight improvement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a loaded question with no one best practice in my opinion. Given the case you have stated (display a table for each `status`) I would use the following thought process:

1. I would generally avoid case A when you're just dealing with one Model type. I try to limit the number of database queries when possible
2. Case B is what I would probably use if the view needs to display different markup depending on the `status` of a task.
3. I would usually tend towards case C if the markup is the same for each `status`. You can use the [group_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) function for this:

When the amount of information on your page starts to get larger and more complicated, you can start looking at extracting some logic out of the controller and into another object (common terms for this object would be a `presenter` or `decorator`). This can make testing some of your presentation logic easier by separating it from the controller and keeping your controllers 'thin'. But for the case you've given, I'd stick with option b or c.

Comment: I can't get the formatting of my code example to work... not sure what's going on. If someone wants to try editing my response that would be swell.

Answer (score 1):

In the simple case where the number of tasks is limited, I would do only a single query to retrieve them, and then separate them as follows:

```
tasks = Task.all
@draft_tasks    = tasks.select { |x| x.status == 'Draft' } 
@approved_tasks = tasks.select { |x| x.status == 'Approved' }
@closed_tasks   = tasks.select { |x| x.status == 'Closed' }
```

Furthermore, depending on the bendability of your requirements, I would even render them in a single table with a clear visual marker what the state is (e.g. background-colour or icons). Then there would not even be a reason to separate the tasks beforehand (but I can imagine this would break your UI completely).

None of the above is valid once the number of tasks becomes larger, and you will need to apply pagination, and you need to display three different tables (one for each state).

In that case you will need to use the three separate queries as answered by @Ben.

Now UI-wise, I am not sure how you can paginate over three different sets of data at once. So instead I would use a single table showing all the states, and offer the option to filter on the status. In that case at least it is clear for the user what pagination will mean.

Just my two cents, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

option a) seems better just because database can cache the query for you and stuff, so it should be faster.

Comment: Thank you, although I feel as though scopes in the model might be an even better option as presented by Ben.

Comment: One query will always be faster than three. But I am not sure speed is a valid argument in this case.

Comment: I'm just saying that's better to let DB to give us the separated entities than separating them with a cycle in ruby. But this actually depends on the number of data fetched. Also it's better if there is needs to use some order or limit. Imagine you want 10 of each and with updated_at ordering. How you do that in a single query??

Comment: That is true, but that is not what you answered first. You said something vague like _and stuff, so it should be faster_. Which honestly, is utter nonsense. A single query with some cycles to separate the data is quicker than three queries. Depending on the number of tasks. Since the OP does not even mention pagination, I suspect the number of tasks is small enough for this to matter. But I agree with your clarification.